# Regex for phone number with standard phone number with brackets

Tags: java, regex, eclipse

This is a question on RegEx in Java. I have looked everywhere but could not find anything similar to what I needed. Also, I have spent hours trying on my own.

I am on the last portion of a school lab coded in Java. I am using Eclipse as my compiler. I have built a membership application using Swing components,

One of my fields is for the user to type in the 10-digit phone number.
However, I had to make this a JFormatted text field, masking the text box it in this format: "(###) ###-####". So when the program is loaded, that text box looks like this: "(**_)** -___"

Now, all I need to do is have a regular expression that will make sure the user types in 10 digits. However, I need it to work with the masked format that I used above. This is what I have so far:

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{3}\\s\\d{3}-\\d{4}");
    matcher = pattern.matcher(phoneText.getText());
    if (!matcher.find())
    {
        phoneText.requestFocus();
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Phone entered incorrectly.  Phone should be:\n" +
                "10 numeric digits.",
                "A D D   E R R O R",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
        return;
    }
```

I believe I have the regEx written to where it accepts the space and the dash in the mask format, but I do not know how to include the parenthesis.

Edit: Adding question in correct format per Andrew Thomas' tip:

What do I need to add to my regEx to include the parenthesis that are already in the formatted text field?

Edit2: Question answered, but adding samples per Bohemians tip so that future students who come across this post can utilize it. Sorry, Im new to this!

Needs to look like:

(123) 456-7890

Comment: *"This is a question on RegEx in Java"*  It might be, but for lack of a question.  What is your question?

Comment: I was wondering what to add to my regEx to include the parenthesis that are already in the formatted text field.

Comment: What, precisely must the regex match? Please list some examples to illustrate your intention

Comment: *"What do I need to add to my regEx to include the parenthesis that are already in the formatted text field?"*  Is a question, and if that is your question, please [edit it into the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/16129115/edit).  Some people will search on '?' (<- yes that question mark, character) to find a question, if the first hit is *"Not the answer you're looking for?"* they will go straight to the next ***actual*** question.  Just a tip..

Comment: Oh wow, what you said makes complete sense. Will do in the future and sorry about that.

Comment: Sorry Bohemian. My question was answered but I changed the post per your suggestion for future students who might stumble across it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to match `(` and `)` (That surround the first 3 digits)

Change it to:

```
pattern = Pattern.compile("\\(\\d{3}\\)\\s\\d{3}-\\d{4}");
                           ^^^      ^^^
```

As you can see, I added `\\` before `(` and `)`. **Why**?

Some characters have special meaning. And since Regexes are Strings in Java, you need to escape them by `\\` (which represents a single `\` in Java).

A double backslash *escapes* special characters to suppress their special meaning, it's like telling:

*"Don't take `(` as **special** character, take it as the regular character `(`"*.

Comment: I'm not even sure this is what he wants :/

Comment: He wants to match `"(###) ###-####"` where `#` are digits.

Comment: hey Maroun Maroun this is exactly what I wanted thank you so much. I didnt add a double backslash before the opening and closing parenthesis. I feel ridiculous.

Comment: @AbinThomas That's how we all learn, from mistakes. Good luck :)

Comment: @AbinThomas you need to know that parenthesis have special meaning before you know that escaping is necessary.

Comment: @ThorbjornRavnAnderson Im sorry I don't understand what you mean by escaping is necessary?

Comment: @MaroundMaround I really appreciate the clarification. You made it very clear when you stated that we escape the strings in java by using \\. Thanks you very much.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `\\(` and `\\)` to use parentheses, try this:

```
Pattern.compile("\\(\\d{3}\\)\\s\\d{3}-\\d{4}");
```

Comment: Thanks. It was my lack of backslashes that was messing me up!

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick solution, when you need to add a brackets in your text-field / phone number field note this is not regex, its jquery based

http://ashfaqahmed.net/jquery-add-prefix-postfix-on-phone-number-field/